# Service for home management (not for rentals and not for HOAs)

Tags: home-ownership

To hold off close voters, I'm asking if a service exists and not for recommendations of a specific provider.  :)

Are there services out there to assist home owners in maintaining the home that they live in?  For example:

- When work needs to be done, finding a good contractor at a good price and managing the work
- Managing regular maintenance like yard work and snow removal
- Maybe paying bills

I realize such services would not be inexpensive but might be helpful especially for older people.

When I try to Google for stuff like this, it just returns info about rental property management and HOAs which are not the same thing (though similar).

Comment: It sounds like you want the same _service_ as those that provide it for rentals - have you asked them if they'll do it for a non-rental?

Comment: I had the same thought as @DStanley - if I were considering this for eg an elderly relative, trying to arrange something with a rental property manager would seem worth investigating.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  It would be ideal if there are companies who specialize in exactly this rather than asking someone to adapt what they do.

Comment: My point is it's not much of an adpatation - rental property management already take care of lawns, repairs, etc. Some may even take care of utility and other bills. So the only thing I see different is that it's not a rental - I don;t kniw why that would matter to the management company.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a [private house manager](https://www.charlottesbestnanny.com/what-is-a-house-manager/):

> A house manager is responsible for handling the daily operations of a
> house and responding to the home owner’s needs. House Managers
> typically supervise and manage things happening daily around the home.
> Their tasks would include things such as **setting appointments for home**
> **repairs and maintenance,** supervising any household staff, keeping an
> inventory of the house and restocking things as needed, making sure
> the house stays neat and organized, **running errands, managing bills**,
> and accounts of the home, providing house sitting and pet sitting
> duties and other tasks as assigned.

At least in the U.S., the process for hiring one can be the same as hiring a nanny (live-in or not). Basically, write up a contract that both your and the manager sign (like any job). The contract should state exactly what the manager's responsibilities are and how they are compensated.

You can find people advertising themselves for this on job websites, or post your own job opening on those sites. I'm sure in more rich/populated areas you can also contact a hiring service that could put you in contact with candidates.

Comment: LOL, supervising household staff is far beyond my needs.  I wonder if this role exists part-time for non uber-wealthy people.

Comment: @gaefan Honestly you can setup the role/job however you want, it's all a matter of finding someone that you like that is willing to do the job. Since it is "private" you can write up the contract however you like (keep in mind that labor laws and taxes still apply...).

Comment: This is the hard part and why I want to find a company that provides the service: "it's all a matter of finding someone that you like that is willing to do the job"